# Tag based on published date

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules

Basically, I'm setting up a website for someone who is going to post one thing per day. I want to provide a way of accessing these articles by week and naming the week:

i.e. if a node is published on the 30th November, I would like the website to *know* that it is the *first week of Advent* and to be able to display that/sort by it.

The current way I was trying to do it was:

> Article Published using Scheduler --> Rules then tags according to
>   date published

I just don't know if that's achievable, or indeed if there's a simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't try this by grouping in views?

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how I would apply the "First Week of Advent" to it in that case. Basically, I'm trying to avoid having the user inputting the article from having to do anything; I want a system that will take the date and output a human name for the day/week/time of year.